# Input in bash script

Tags: shell-script

I have a script like this:

```
for i in *.TF; 
do
my command $i 
done
```

The problem is, each command line needs a same input (in this case: `/PS`)
how can I do this? I have tested some methods like:

```
/PS | ./mybash.csh
```

It only works in first iteration.
Just in case, /PS is some text (input) and I want feed it as input to each iteration of my command.

Comment: Is `/PS` a program or some text? Do you want to feed that as input to each iteration of `my command`?

Comment: do you mean `echo /PS`?

Answer (score 1):

To also address the question *"each command line needs a same input"*, in case that more or different commands are involved that should be fed from the same source, you can use `yes`:

```
yes "/PS" | my_script
```

Answer (score 0):

simply write line below in a file call `run.sh`

```
for i in *.TF 
do
  my command "$i"  < /PS
done
```

then run

```
bash run.sh
```

where

- `bash` can replace by  `ksh`
- juste in case some files have whitespace you should enclose $i in quotes like `"$i"`
- `my command` stand for a more complete command line (or you have a `my` programm in your `$PATH`)
- this syntax in not a csh syntax by the way.